# Keep script running while computer is in suspension mode

Tags: shell-script, suspend, battery

I'm using a simple script, launched when I start the X session, to check my battery level and, if it's below a fixed threshold, invoke `systemctl hibernate`.
However, when I suspend the laptop with `systemctl suspend`, the script obviously can't check the battery level. For this reason, it may happen that it shutdowns completely.

Is there any way to keep the script running even if the laptop is suspended?

Comment: No, user space is frozen. See information about [power states](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt) in documentation.

Answer (score 5):

No, when the system goes into hibernation or suspend mode, all user-level activity is suspended and will not resume until the system has left that mode.  It is not possible to keep a script running (performing actions) *during* hibernation or suspension.

Related Ask Ubuntu question regarding "hybrid suspension" and "suspend to both RAM and disk": [How do I use pm-suspend-hybrid by default instead of pm-suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, how do other systems (Desktop Environments?) do that? I remember that when I had Ubuntu, when the laptop was suspended and the battery level dropped below a certain threshold, the system was resumed from suspension and immediately put to hibernation mode. Does this work in the kernel user space?

Comment: @tigerjack89 I suspect that was something done by the kernel, not a user-level program. I'm unfamiliar with that particular feature of Ubuntu.

Comment: @tigerjack89 See update.